# Does this graph show homoscedasticity or heteroscedasticity? Are the errors random?

Tags: heteroscedasticity, graphical-model, residuals

[image]

I think this graph shows homoscedasticity. Is this true?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the community. While most of us might be able to infer that this is probably a predicted vs residual plot, it would still help to have a little bit of context (so, maybe tell us what we're looking at).

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, the linear association between those two variables is too low to know for sure. I'd also go with homoskedasticity, but in this case it won't matter much since there is practically no correlation between the variables...

Comment: How did you get the strength of linear association between the variables out of that graph? (I'm genuinely curious, it can be hard to convey that on the internet)

Comment: If you try to wrap the points within an ellipse, you'll get a very fat ellipse which almost resembles a circle. Also, since the scale of the variable on the y axis is smaller, that means the points are even more spread in the up-down direction than they look in the graph, which in this case will make the ellipse even fatter. You get high associations for instance (although there are other ways) when the scatterplot looks like a thin tilted ellipse.

Comment: oh, I thought this was a predicted vs residual plot (the mean on the y axis seems to be zero). As i stated in my comment to the OP, the vague context of this graph makes it difficult to interpret.

Comment: You are right. He's probably looking for random errors in order to have a "valid" regression. So zero association would be his best case scenario right?

Comment: yes, i believe so. His graph seems to indicate constant error (if that is indeed predicted vs residual), and the regression I assume hes doing has that particular assumption met.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I am indeed trying to prove that there are random errors in the regression. This graph measures the predicted results against the residuals. If you look at the following link you can see the regression I created Any comments on what I did with this regression would also be greatly appreciated:

http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185380/i-need-to-find-explanatory-variables-and-instrumental-variables-on-the-returns-o?noredirect=1#comment352175_185380

Comment: These comments are baffling, because homoscedasticity has nothing at all to do with "linear association" or "constant error."  It refers only to how the *spread* of the residuals (as shown on the vertical axis) might vary with the predicted value (as shown on the horizontal axis).

Comment: I tend not to believe assumptions, but in this case I think it would be fair to assume your regression is not that bad. I would try some kind of variable selection, though, because you have many non-significant variables.

Comment: @whuber I know, but if there is zero association between the variables, then there it doesn't make much sense to talk about homoskedasticity. What do you think?

Comment: Please forgive me for repeating myself: homoscedasticity has *absolutely nothing to do* with the association. Even with zero association it is a valid concept, meaningful, and well-defined.  For instance, $(X,Y)$ data generated according to the model $Y\sim N(0, (X\sigma)^2)$ would have no association (linear or otherwise), because $E(Y|X)=0$, yet would be strongly heteroscedastic.

Comment: @whuber: Tracking that association has nothing to with scedasticity. I suppose I meant to say constant variance, as opposed to constant error in my earlier comment. Is it correct to remove the comment (beginning with "yes, I believe so"), or should it be left? (as it can no longer be edited).

Comment: I know it is well defined and all that, but sometimes well-defined concepts have no use in certain scenarios. For example, if X and Y are independent and uniformly distributed, they have no linear association and _in this case_, implies that speaking about homoskedasticity will get you nowhere. The point is: being well-defined doesn't always imply that you'll get anything useful from it.

Comment: But let's not dwell in this conversation and move on ^^